# Slow start, slow end fade curve

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm looking for a curve that has a slow start and a slow end, as an audio workstation put it. It fails to mention, however what kind of curve it is.

More accurately, I'm looking for a curve like this:

- Begins at $x = a$, ends at $x = a+t$, so has length $t$
- $f'(a) = 0$, $f'(a+t) = 0$
- Bonus if $f'(x)=0$ for $x \in ]-\infty,a]$ and $x \in ]a+t,\infty]$ so one can avoid partially defining
- Bonus if the steepness of the middle point can be altered

The curve looks something like this:
[image: Slow start, slow end]

A half of a sine wave is pretty close, but not quite. I'm sure there is even a name for this kind of thing, but I've never encountered it before.

Comment: A logistic function?

Comment: @AndrewLi That's the one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into the logistic function 
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-ax}}$$
for restricted domain (if you want a start and end point). The steepness of the curve at the PoI can be altered by adjusting $a$. This doesn’t satisfy exactly $f’(a)=0$ but it’s a decent approximation

[image]

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function